# Copy initialization of the form '= {}'

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, list-initialization, copy-initialization

Given the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class X;

class Y
{
public:
  Y() { printf("  1\n"); }             // 1
  // operator X(); // 2
};

class X
{
public:
  X(int) {}
  X(const Y& rhs) { printf("  3\n"); } // 3
  X(Y&& rhs) { printf("  4\n"); }      // 4
};

// Y::operator X() { printf("   operator X() - 2\n"); return X{2}; }

int main()
{
  Y y{};     // Calls (1)

  printf("j\n");
  X j{y};    // Calls (3)
  printf("k\n");
  X k = {y}; // Calls (3)
  printf("m\n");
  X m = y;   // Calls (3)
  printf("n\n");
  X n(y);    // Calls (3)

  return 0;
}
```

So far, so good. Now, if I enable the conversion operator `Y::operator X()`, I get this;-

```
  X m = y; // Calls (2)
```

My understanding is that this happens because (2) is 'less const' than (3) and
therefore preferred. The call to the `X` constructor is elided

My question is, why doesn't the definition `X k = {y}` change its behavior in the same way? I know that `= {}` is technically 'list copy initialization', but in the absence of a constructor taking an `initializer_list` type, doesn't this revert to 'copy initialization' behavior? ie - the same as for `X m = y`

Where is the hole in my understanding?

Comment: I'm sorry - I messed up minimising the code - corrected (hopefully)

Comment: Exaxt compiler used?  I am aware of inconsistencies in code adjacent to this in some compilers.

Comment: Improved the example. I've tried this with compiler tool on cppreference.com (clang 3.8) in 11, 14, and 17 modes. The result is the same

Comment: Thank you all for your help and comprehensive answers. I think I understand what's going on now. But I have to agree with Barry's sentiment - C++ initialisation is nuts! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Where is the hole in my understanding?

tltldr; Nobody understands initialization.

tldr; List-initialization prefers `std::initializer_list<T>` constructors, but it doesn't fall-back to non-list-initialization. It only falls back to considering constructors. Non-list-initialization will consider conversion functions, but the fallback does not.

---

All of the initialization rules come from [[dcl.init]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17). So let's just go from first principles.

[[dcl.init]/17.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.1):

> - If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) *braced-init-list* or is = *braced-init-list*, the object or reference is list-initialized.

The first first bullet point covers any list-initialization. This jumps `X x{y}`  and `X x = {y}` over to [[dcl.init.list]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list). We'll get back to that. The other case is easier. Let's look at `X x = y`. We call straight down into:

[[dcl.init]/17.6.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.3):

> - Otherwise (i.e., for the remaining copy-initialization cases), user-defined conversion sequences that can convert from the source type to the destination type or (when a conversion function is used) to a derived class thereof are enumerated as described in [[over.match.copy]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.copy), and the best one is chosen through overload resolution.

The candidates in [over.match.copy] are:

> - The converting constructors of `T` [in our case, `X`] are candidate functions.
> - When the type of the initializer expression is a class type “*cv* `S`”, the non-explicit conversion functions of `S` and its base classes are considered.
>
> In both cases, the argument list has one argument, which is the initializer expression.

This gives us candidates:

```
X(Y const &);     // from the 1st bullet
Y::operator X();  // from the 2nd bullet
```

The 2nd is equivalent to having had a `X(Y& )`, since the conversion function is not cv-qualified. This makes for a less cv-qualified reference than the converting constructor, so it's preferred. Note, there is no invocation of `X(X&& )` here in C++17.

---

Now let's go back to the list-initialization cases. The first relevant bullet point is [[dcl.init.list]/3.6](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3.6):

> Otherwise, if `T` is a class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen through overload resolution ([over.match], [over.match.list]). If a narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert any of the arguments, the program is ill-formed.

which in both cases takes us to [[over.match.list]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.list) which defines two-phase overload resolution:

> - Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors ([dcl.init.list]) of the class T and the argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument.
> - If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class T and the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list.
>
> If the initializer list has no elements and T has a default constructor, the first phase is omitted. In copy-list-initialization, if an explicit constructor is chosen, the initialization is ill-formed.

The candidates are the constructors of `X`. The only difference between `X x{y}` and `X x = {y}` are that if the latter chooses an `explicit` constructor, the initialization is ill-formed. We don't even have any `explicit` constructors, so the two are equivalent. Hence, we enumerate our constructors:

- `X(Y const& )`
- `X(X&& )` by way of `Y::operator X()`

The former is a direct reference binding that is an Exact Match. The latter requires a user-defined conversion. Hence, we prefer `X(Y const& )` in this case.

---

Note that gcc 7.1 gets this wrong in C++1z mode, so I've filed [bug 80943](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80943).

Comment: You are not "told to consider conversion functions" because they are instead considered when determining whether the copy/move constructors of `X` are viable candidates. They just can't compete with an exact-match reference binding.

Comment: @T.C. So `X x{y}` will consider `X(X&&)` by way of `Y::operator X` a viable candidate, just a less viable one? Or in other words, the gcc bug I filed is a bug but not for the reasons I described?

Comment: Pretty much, yes.

Comment: The bug you reported also happens for `T t(s)`

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, why doesn't the definition X k = {y} change its behavior in the same way?

Because, conceptually speaking, a `= { .. }` is an *initialization* for something that automatically chooses the "best" way to initialize the target *from the braces*, while `= value` is also an initialization, but conceptually also a conversion of the *value* to a different value. The conversion is completely symmetric: If will look into the source value to see whether it provides a way to create the target, and will look into the target to see whether it provides a way to accept the source.

If your target type is `struct A { int x; }` then using `= { 10 }` will not try to convert the `10` to `A` (which will fail). But it will seek the best (in their eyes) form of initialization, which here amounts to aggregate initialization. However if `A` is not an aggregate (add constructors), then it will call the constructors, where in your case it finds the `Y` accepted readily without a conversion needed. There is no such symmetry between the source and the target like there is with the conversion when using the `= value` form.

Your suspicion about the "less const" of the conversion function is exactly right. If you make the conversion function a const member, then it will become ambiguous.